# jQuery toggle slide doesn't slide back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm following a tutorial on PluralSight. So I've basically entered all the code exactly as it appears in the lesson. Yet mine doesn't work.

Here's the HTML:

```
<header>
    <a href="#" id="toggleMenu"><img src="images/menu.png" /></a>
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <li id="menuOut"><img src="images/back.png" /></li>
            <li class="selected"><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Company Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
    #toggleMenu, #menuOut{
        display: none;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 40.063em) {

    #toggleMenu{
        display: block;
        margin: 30px;
    }
   #menuOut{
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 30px 0 40px 30px;
    header ul{
        background: #00abd0;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -30px;
        left: -20px;
    }

    header ul li{
        display: block !important;
        clear: both;
        background: #00A1c4;
        width: 100%;
    }
```

(I've only included what I think are the important bits to this problem, not all the CSS!)

And here's the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#toggleMenu').click(function(){
       $(".row ul").toggle('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500);
    });

    $('#menuOut').click(function(){
       $('.row ul').toggle('slide', {direction: 'left'}, 500); 
    });

});
```

In the video, when the browser is resized, it works great, the button shows up, he clicks it, the menu slides out, click again, it goes back out. With mine, this is what I see when I click:

[Menu expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IudK.jpg)

And when I click again, nothing happens. I also can't figure out why the list element where the back button is placed is highlighted. No where in the CSS is it written for it to be highlighted.

Comment: That must be an old tut, because `toggle()` used that way is obsolete. If you want the new slide method, I think it's `slideToggle()`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you sing?

Comment: I'm using jQuery version 3.1.1!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is `slideToggle()`. As follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#toggleMenu').click(function(){
         $(".row ul").slideToggle(500);
     });

     $('#menuOut').click(function(){
        $('.row ul').slideToggle(500); 
     });
 });
```

```css
    #toggleMenu, #menuOut{
        display: none;
    }

@media only screen and (max-width: 40.063em) {

    #toggleMenu{
        display: block;
        margin: 30px;
    }
   #menuOut{
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin: 30px 0 40px 30px;
    }
    header ul{
        background: #00abd0;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: -30px;
        left: -20px;
    }

    header ul li{
        display: block !important;
        clear: both;
        background: #00A1c4;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <a href="#" id="toggleMenu"><img src="images/menu.png" /></a>
    <div class="row">
        <ul>
            <li id="menuOut"><img src="images/back.png" /></li>
            <li class="selected"><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Company Overview</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Specials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Press</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</header>
```